# Is it possible to keep a gradient Stationary while rotating

Tags: css, css-animations

I am attempting to rotate a 'cog' using CSS (an SVG cog).

However I was wondering if it was possible to keep the gradient at a constant angle so that it appears more realistic.

e.g. cog rotates `20deg` using CSS transforms but the gradient stays at `0deg` so it looks like there is a constant light source.

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just animate the background angle from 360 to 0 while animation the rotation from 0 to 360. it will make the background stay static. for make available animation of background angle use `CSS.registerProperty`.

As here:

```js
CSS.registerProperty({
  name: '--deg',
  syntax: '<angle>',
  inherits: false,
  initialValue: '0deg',
});
```

```css
:root {
  --deg: 0deg;
}
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
#d {
overflow:hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  margin:auto;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--deg), red, yellow, green);
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: rotation 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg); --deg: 360deg}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg); --deg: 0deg}
}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it lead me to the correct answer so I will mark it as correct (as it answered my question I just forgot to say it was SVG and unfortunately this doesn't work for that.) If you can work out how to do it in an SVG then that would be amazing!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that you can't rotate the gradient in an SVG with CSS (or at least I couldn't find it if you can).

Instead using native SVG rotation on the gradient was the solution.

They key is to add the following within the `<linearGradient>`

```
    <animateTransform
  attributeName="gradientTransform"
  type="rotate"
  from="0 250 250"
  to="360 250 250"
  dur="10s"
  repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cog {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  animation: rotation-0 10s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes rotation-0 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="cog" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 44 44" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" style="stop-color:#28b493;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="80%" style="stop-color:#007c9b;stop-opacity:1" />
      <animateTransform
  attributeName="gradientTransform"
  type="rotate"
  from="0 22 22"
  to="360 22 22"
  dur="10s"
  repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

 <path fill="url(#grad)" d="M44,24.707v-5.5l-6.574-2.738c-0.184-0.516-0.377-1.015-0.613-1.505l2.656-6.606l-3.891-3.889l-6.549,2.696   c-0.498-0.242-1.008-0.445-1.535-0.634L24.707,0h-5.5l-2.718,6.509c-0.548,0.194-1.075,0.397-1.595,0.646L8.357,4.528L4.469,8.416   l2.665,6.478c-0.259,0.532-0.467,1.074-0.667,1.633L0,19.293v5.5l6.472,2.697c0.199,0.559,0.413,1.1,0.67,1.633l-2.615,6.52   l3.888,3.889l6.494-2.676c0.522,0.248,1.054,0.447,1.601,0.635L19.293,44h5.5l2.721-6.543c0.523-0.193,1.039-0.396,1.533-0.633   l6.596,2.643l3.889-3.889l-2.709-6.562c0.232-0.494,0.418-0.994,0.602-1.504L44,24.707z M21.957,31.583   c-5.289,0-9.582-4.292-9.582-9.583s4.293-9.583,9.582-9.583c5.292,0,9.583,4.293,9.583,9.583S27.248,31.583,21.957,31.583z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box-cirlce {width:100%; position:relative;}

.cog-small {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url('https://ladaworld.com/299-large_default/differential-24-splines-side-gear.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

#cog {
 -webkit-animation: cog 5s infinite;   
 -moz-animation: cog 5s infinite;
 -ms-animation: cog 5s infinite;    
 animation: cog 5s infinite;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
 -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;  
 -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-timing-function: linear 
}
@-webkit-keyframes cog {
100%{ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
@-moz-keyframes cog {
100%{ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
@-ms-keyframes cog {
100%{ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
@keyframes cog {
100%{ 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
 transform: rotate(360deg)
}
}
```

```html
<div class="box-cirlce"><div class="cog-small" id="cog"></div></div>
```

Comment: I think the question was not how rotate the shape, but how rotate the shape, while its background not rotating...

Comment: Yeah my fault, it was impossible to create a fiddle as the fiddle ended up being more misleading than helpful. Yosef is correct I wanted a static gradient within a rotating shape.